# How are the bonuses calculated?

Tags: rebuild-the-universe

When you bought/created enough particles of a certain species, a bonus is unlocked. Each has a tooltip with something like:

> Effect: +1% APS

Is this effect for the overall APS, or just for that one specific species?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each bonus is for that specific particle/specie. I didn't look good enough. In the following screenshot it is clear that there is a difference between the quantum foam and neutrino's, what is exactly coming from the differences in the bonuses.

[image: Difference foam and neutrino's]